# Netbeans won't display web project in Projects Tab

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm running NetBeans 7.3 on Ubuntu 12.10. I'm taking a course in Java Web Development, so I have a project called jsage8 that contains my work for the course. Previously this project was displayed in the Projects tab just fine, but now opening the project doesn't do anything. It just says "No Project Open" when I click to open it in the Open Project menu. It will however open a normal Java Project folder that isn't a web based project. Currently there's only an index.jps, a .html file, and a .css file in the project, is it not displaying because there's no .java files present?

Feeling a bit helpless here and I can't seem to google anything that addresses this specific issue so I'm wondering if I've just done something wrong?

NOTE: I can navigate to the directory the files in and open them in NetBeans manually, but the projects tab remains blank. I can even click "Run Project" and build the project and have it display in a web browser using my local Tomcat server with no issues also.

NOTE: The jsage8 project also doesn't show up in the "Recent Projects" menu whereas other projects do.

NOTE: I can even right click the index.jsp's file tab once opened in NetBeans and click "Select in Projects" which opens the prompt "Do you want to open project jsage8" I click Ok and nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I ran the update for NetBeans and everything seems to be working fine now (even though just restarting it had done nothing). If you're having a problem similar to this try updating NetBeans and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try. I've been having the same using except I'm running on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Do you install fully features which contain Web Development plugin?
I think you forgot it already

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you are trying to say. Did I install a version of Netbeans that supports Web Development? Yes, I installed the full version that supports Web Development and several non-core programming languages in addition to installing the included Tomcat server that comes along with it. I'm not sure what caused this problem in the first place, but updating Netbeans fixed the symptom as I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Windows

Locate the project on your pc, once located in the folder-> **properties** -> **security** -> edit the permissions-> **full control** activated -> accept. After that I restarted ***Apache Netbeans 11.3*** and I was able to open my project normally.

*My problem was that I couldn't open any web application in apache netbeans.*